# Store Codeship build ID in variable using GREP

Tags: json, bash, curl, grep, codeship

I am trying to use a grep to search a JSON output, I used a curl command to return the data from a particular codeship build and I want to use GREP to store said ID value in a variable. However after I run the command and try to echo out the value of the variable its blank.

Below are the commands:

```
export API_KEY=abc123
export PROJECT_ID=123456
export LAST_BUILD_ID=$(curl -s https://codeship.com/api/v1/projects/$PROJECT_ID.json?api_key=$API_KEY | grep -Eo '"builds":\[{"id":\d+' | grep -Eo --color=never '\d+' | tail -1)
export LAST_BUILD_URL=$(echo "https://codeship.com/api/v1/builds/$LAST_BUILD_ID/restart.json?api_key=$API_KEY")
```

Answer (score 0):

My response : **never** use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) nor [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) to parse [json](/questions/tagged/json).

Instead, use a proper [json](/questions/tagged/json) parser.

In shell, take a look to [jq](/questions/tagged/jq).

Example, adapt it a bit :

```
#!/bin/bash

API_KEY=abc123
PROJECT_ID=123456
html=$(curl -s https://codeship.com/api/v1/projects/$PROJECT_ID.json?api_key=$API_KEY)
LAST_BUILD_ID=$(jq '.builds | .[] | .never' <<< "$html") # just guessing
LAST_BUILD_URL=$(echo "https://codeship.com/api/v1/builds/$LAST_BUILD_ID/restart.json?api_key=$API_KEY")
```

#### Note

If you provide the JSON, I will be able to be more specific with the `jq` command

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, but I already tried jq, but it didn't work so well for me seeing as I'm actually using it in a Lambda function, do you have any idea how to use jq in a Lambda function?

Comment: Can yo define the level of Lambda ? Do you mean the AWS service or a inline python or anything else ?

Comment: It was the AWS service